# set BRANDNAME not working when call paypal's SetExpressCheckout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I set Brandname as requested in paypal's document:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

I am using sandbox to test and can see that BRANDNAME was set in the request, however, on paypal's checkout page, it still show as My Test store, other than whatever I set in brand name.

Can someone help?

Many Thanks

Comment: It probably has to do with the VERSION value that you're sending.  @Eshan's example is using version 109.0, so I'd make sure you're using that at a minimum.  The current API version is 121.0

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I tested it at my end and it works fine for me . See the below parameters and the attached screen shot .

NVP Request:

```
USER=XXXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXX&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/index.php?action=ECreturn&CANCELURL=http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/index.php?action=ECcancel&AMT=0.01&PAYMENTACTION=Authorization&BRANDNAME=ABCDEFGH
```

NVP Response:

```
TOKEN=EC-85C13366BX6520717
TIMESTAMP=2015-03-15T13:29:56Z
CORRELATIONID=77262af85819a
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=15735246 

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-85C13366BX6520717
```

[image]

Comment: worked it out. I was using an example code, which has &VERSION=56 set. Your code has version=109. Looks like version 56 doesn't support brandname override